# Prevent SQL overwrite with null value if some value exists in column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to ascertain the best way to achieve a certain constraint. The constraint being that if there is a non-null value already present in the column, I need to prevent it from ever getting updated with a null value. It should still be receptive to non-null updates. Just that if a null update is run against this constraint on a column where a non null value is already present, I need to prevent that

example ->

Column name: Lname

```
> t0: Lname = NULL
> t1: update Lname - > Dracula (ALLOWED)
> t2: update Lname - > daniel (ALLOWED)
> t3: update Lname - > NULL  (DISALLOW THIS)
> t4: Final state Lname -> daniel (FINAL STATE)
```

I can think of doing this programatically by fetching the row from db and comparing the current value against the incoming value. But I wonder if there is a better solution to this.

A not null constraint won't work because when the first time the row is created, it can carry null values inside these columns.

Using postgres with typeORM currently.

Would be extremely grateful for any thoughts/pointers!

Comment: This could be done with a trigger

Comment: You're looking for coalesce

Comment: coalesce would be the easy way. like "update Lname=coalesce('Dracula',Lname)"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with a constraint.

The best way to do that would be a trigger. That could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_set_null() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF OLD.col1 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.col1 IS NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot change "col1" to NULL';
   END IF;

   IF OLD.col2 IS NOT NULL AND NEW.col2 IS NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot change "col2" to NULL';
   END IF;

   ...

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER no_set_null BEFORE UPDATE ON atable
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE no_set_null();
```

You might also be able to come up with a generic trigger function for that, but it would be complicated, and perhaps the performance would not be as good.

Comment: trigger is quite expensive, coalesce should be way faster. but has the drawback : direct sql-session can still null the entry. safe=trigger, fast=coalesce (only if update-statements are under full-control)

Comment: @MichaelHauptmann Well, that would be "just don't do it". I think OP was asking for a way to prevent the application from doing it. I admit it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be to write a pl-pgsql procedure for doing the update and force the app to use the procedure. You could revoke update on the table from the app user(s) so the only way to update the table is through the procedure.